# can we use Qt(64) to produce an application that will work on both 32bit windows and 64bit windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, windows64

http://qt-project.org/downloads . I downloaded the openGL since many say this set standard is better. but now i got requirement from my prof that I need to provide something that can work on windows 32/64. Is there any way that i do not have to install Qt for windows 32 and produce an application that can be run on windows 32?

what I am saying is that I only installed Qt for win64 but now I want something can work on win32 platform. so I suppose one way is to install Qt for win32 and create a new project. But I want to ask whether I can maybe do some configuration and produce something that can work on win32 using the installed Qt on win64 on my com

thanks!

Comment: No, you cant run win32 Qt applicatons without win32 Qt runtime. Do you have any arguments to create x64 applicatoin? Why you couldn't create simple win32 app? Note: all win32 apps will run on win64.

Comment: what I am saying I only installed Qt for win64 but now I want something can work on win32 platform. so I suppose one way is to install Qt for win32 and create a new project. But I want to ask whether I can maybe do some configuration and produce something that can work on win32 using the installed Qt on win64 on my com @DmitrySazonov

Comment: You can install x64 OS over your 32-bit system (if your CPU supports it). Or you can install x64 OS on virtual machine. But it will be much easier to compile your program for 32-bit OS and use 32-bit version of Qt.

Comment: @Dmitry Sazonov can we use Qt add in for VS to have both 64 bit and 32 bit?

Comment: It does not depends on Qt Addin. First, you should understand some basics: what is complier, IDE, target platform, addin.

Comment: thanks. kind of get it. so the addin is only going to provide a library and some extensions. so I should say whether it is x86 or x64 only depends on my project configuration in VS? but if I use my Qt creator to do the application, i have to use Qt for win32?

Comment: I think that you should use win32 everywhere. And don't think about it for now. Your questions is too common - you should expand your common knowlenge of programming by reading books / google etc, instead of asking such questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For Windows Vista and up, there's no reason not to use the ANGLE implementation of OpenGL that's bundled with Qt. "many say tis set standard is better" - this is false unless you can guarantee that your customers have a decent OpenGL-supporting graphics card driver installed on their machine. I'd suggest forgetting about system OpenGL, and use ANGLE implementations.
2. It's trivial to compile your project for both 32 and 64 bit Qt, if you really need the 64 bit address space. For many applications, there's no reason at all to provide a 64 bit version.

Comment: thanks for your reply. and sorry about my misunderstanding of OpenGL. the only reason I installed that is that I wanted to try something new. of course some computers may not support OpenGL completely. but this is not the key point. I used 64 bit version since my com is 64 bit and I suppose 64 bit may run a bit faster than 32 bit version. of course 32 bit application should work on fine on 64 bit machine

Comment: @JunchaoGu Why do you think that 64 bit programs will run faster? Main major difference it that 64 bit programs have no 2-GB limit of virtual memory.

Comment: @JunchaoGu: If you think something is faster, you better have measurements to show the difference. Otherwise you're just making up fantasies. There's a lot of such fantasies around, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it directly.
The only way to launch 64-bit applications on 32-bit Windows is to use emulators and virtual machines, for instance VMWare. But it reduces the application performance.

Comment: so I should compile my app as x86? but is there any easy way to achieve this other than installing Qt for x86 (I have Qt for x64 now) on my com?

Comment: x86 processor know nothing about x64 command set, so yes, you need to compile your app as x86. Qt libraries also should be x86.